# Django: Call a rest API using json in params is not working

Tags: python, html, api, rest, django-views

I have this data and I convert it to json and then I call a Java API using data as params but it's not working.

```
 data = {"clientId": "CAxsRoZcH063XwCtHCVZItVq0Hga", "clientSecret": "ifs6nU9ZZQitOOqYr5Hy579sa28a", "username":"doctor1","password":"fistar"}
 json_data = json.dumps(data)
 user = requests.post(url='http://147.27.50.130:8080/EHR_SE/UserLogin', params=json_data)
```

When I change params to an html string it's working

```
 user = requests.post(url='http://147.27.50.130:8080/EHR_SE/UserLogin', params="data=%7B%22clientId%22%3A%22CAxsRoZcH063XwCtHCVZItVq0Hga%22%2C%22clientSecret%22%3A%22ifs6nU9ZZQitOOqYr5Hy579sa28a%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22doctor1%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22fistar%22%7D")
```

Do you have any idea how to convert this json string to the correct format?

To clarify the API is accepting json strings. When I call the api from browser using code below it's working.

```
<form action="UserLogin" method="POST">
<input type='text' name='data' value='{"clientId":"CAxsRoZcH063XwCtHCVZItVq0Hga","clientSecret":"ifs6nU9ZZQitOOqYr5Hy579sa28a","username":"doctor1","password":"fistar"}'>
<input type="submit" value="Identification">
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: If you are using JSON I believe you want to use the `data=json_data` keyword argument for `request.post()`. [Relevant docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I should have included the keyword `data=` in params.

The proposed solution is:

```
 user = requests.post(url='http://147.27.50.130:8080/EHR_SE/UserLogin', params="data="+json_data)
```

Comment: That might work but I don't think you are usign that properly. it should just be `requests.post(url='http://147.27.50.130:8080/EHR_SE/UserLogin', data=json_data)`

Comment: @IanAuld  tried earlier your proposed solution but unfortunately is not working.